# Robots.txt vs. Noindex Tags

Tags: seo, robots.txt, noindex

According to matt cutts, even though we block the page using Robots.txt , it is better using noindex tag. ( Source : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0)

If it is blocked by Robots.txt, how Google bot read whether it has noindex tag or not? Because as I know if it blocked by Robots.txt, Google will not read any thing in that post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch! If you're blocking a page with robots.txt then crawlers will not able able to read the noindex meta tag. In these cases you should send the x-robots-tag HTTP header either via server-side code or `.htaccess`.

`.htaccess` example:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

Sample PHP code:

header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex');